# Why doesn't the function definition end when I hit Enter?

Tags: python

After I type `return`, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I think I should be able to see a new prompt in my Python shell.

Usually, when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the shell, it turn to a new prompt. But this time it didn't. The new prompt line appears only after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. Why?

My code is

```
def nobo():
    x=4
    print x
    return
```

Comment: Because you *could* continue the function. Functions can have multiple return lines for different cases, and although in this example any code after the return would be unreachable, it is still valid syntax.

Comment: For the second question: Maybe surround with a `try-except`

Comment: Then what kind of things should be typed in if you wanna continue? I try some but I get traceback.

Answer (score 4):

Just hit <kbd>Return</kbd> again. This empty line will the the Python interpreter that your  `def` is finished. `return` is not enought because there may follow code (which, of course, will not be reachable).

```
>>> def foo():
...     return
... 
>>>
```

If you want to continue the definiton, you'll have to type something:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 1 + 2;
...     print(1)
...     return
... 
>>>
```

*Any* empty line will end the `def` *in the interpreter*.

**Pro Tip:**

Write your code in a `.py` file and execute it.

```
$ python mycode.py
```

Comment: But what should be typed in the empty new line if you don't wan't to end the definition?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @walkerlala what do you mean? You should type whatever you want in the next line of the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for example, if I continue to type "print 78" (not indented), then I get error.

Comment: If you don't indent, you will get an error. Type *an empty line*, then continue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean what kind of things can I type in the empty line

Comment: @walkerlala you can type *"things"* that are valid Python, but any subsequent line still has to be indented, to remain part of the function. If you want a new line outside the function, wait until you're back to the prompt.

Comment: @LutzHorn what is "type an empty line"?

Comment: An empty line contains nothing, that's why it is empty. Hit the "Enter" key (which is called the "Return" key above) twice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it. I'm  just a little curious about why python shell don't indent things automatically for you if you have to indent?

Comment: @walkerlala it automatically dedents after a `return`, because that's expected to be the end of the current block.

Comment: What could meaningfully come after `return`?  A comment, indented to the same level.